# Set Details In Error Response Http Call (Using GRPC) In Python

Tags: python, error-handling, grpc

I have an API with this proto like :

```
service SmartLocationFavourites {
  rpc SmartSuggestion(SmartSuggestionRequest) returns (SmartSuggestionReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/api/v3/smartSuggestion"
    };
  };
}

message ErrorDetail {
  string code = 1;
  optional string payload = 2;
}
```

Additional to `SmartSuggestionReply` response, I want to have a grpc_error_handler which returns error when error occurs.
The sample of error i want is like this:

```
{
    "code": 3,
    "message": "MY MESSAGE",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/SmartLocationFavourites.v1.ErrorDetail",
            "code": "MY_SAMPLE_ERROR_CODE"
        }
    ]
}
```

the problem is i cant set details and message in python (with using return or rise an error)